# Why isn't this object loop working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I want to loop through this object and add the 'loc' value to an array if their side = 2. What am I doing wrong?

2025 is the the room object and the entire things is rooms.

```
//Object
    {
      "2025": {
        "tom": {
          "side": 1,
          "loc": 111
        },
        "billy": {
          "side": 2,
          "loc": 222
        },
        "joe": {
          "side": 2,
          "loc": 333
        },
        "bob": {
          "side": 1,
          "loc": 444
        }
      }
    }

//Code
    var side2 = [];
    for (var key in rooms[room]) {
       if (rooms[room].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var obj = rooms[room][key];
          for (var prop in obj) {
             if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                     if(prop == 'loc') {
                         if(obj[prop] == 2) {
                            side2.push(key);
                         }

                 }
             }
          }
       }
    }
    console.log(side2);
```

Comment: Because no `loc` property has the vaue `2`? Stepping through this in the debugger ought to help you to figure it out. But why are you looping through the keys for find `loc` anyway? You can just do `obj.loc`.

Comment: Yeah there is no value 2 for `loc` but for `side`. You want to do something like `if(prop == 'side') {
                         if(obj[prop] == 2) {
                            side2.push(key);
                         }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to push when the `side` value is `2`, so you want to check `side` and not `loc`. Then you can simply push `obj.loc`

```
...
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
     if(prop == 'side') {
         if(obj[prop] == 2) {
            side2.push(obj.loc);
         }
     }
 }
...
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oo91hg13/)

---

That being said you can shorten this code quite a bit, removing unneeded looping and work you can shorten all your code to simply:

```
for (var key in rooms[room]) {
    var item = rooms[room][key];
    if(item.side == 2) 
        side2.push(item.loc)
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/oo91hg13/1/)

Answer (score 0):

From your statement, you want to push the value of `loc` property to the array `side2` if the value of `side` property is 2.

But in your code

```
if(prop == 'loc') {
   if(obj[prop] == 2) {
      side2.push(key);
   }
}
```

You are comparing the value of `loc` property to be 2, not the value of `side` property. you probably need something like

```
if(prop == 'side') {
   if(obj[prop] == 2) {
      side2.push(obj['loc']);
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this different/better from just replacing the whole loop with `side2.push(obj.side)`?

Comment: i belive he said he wished to add the value of `loc` property to the `side2` array and not the value of `obj.side`. And also according to his statement in question  **He wants to add the vlaue of the property loc to the array (side2)**. so i don't know why he is adding `key` to it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments and other answers, you are looking for a `loc` property of `2` which doesn't exist. So the immediate problem can be solved by replacing `loc` with `side` (assuming that's what you want).

But your code can be simplified. Looping at the top level is fine. However, the entire nested loop part of your code:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
     if(prop == 'loc') {
       if(obj[prop] == 2) {
         side2.push(key);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

can be replaced with

```
if (obj.side == 2) side2.push(key);
```

In other words, you don't need to loop through an object's properties to find a particular one (`side` in this case). You can just access it, with `obj.side`.

You can also conceive of this problem as wanting to filter the list of rooms down to those with people with a `loc` of 2, in which case you could write:

```
Object.keys(rooms) . filter(hasPeopleWithLoc(2))
```

where

```
function hasPeopleWithLoc(loc) {
  return function(roomKey) {
    var room = rooms[roomKey];
    return Object.keys(room) . some(function(personKey) {
      return room[personKey].loc === loc;
    });
  };
}
```

Note that this code will leave you with just one entry for a room in the result if anyone in that room has a `loc` of 2. Your original code behaves slightly differently; it puts an entry for the room in the result for **each** person in that room with the desired `loc`.

Comment: This is all nice information for the OP to know to remove unnecessary work and shorten their code. But how is this a solution to their problem at hand? The OP isn't looking to add all the values of `side` into an array.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No, actually he appears to want to push the room number into the array.